# access current element in a property in react

Tags: reactjs, css

How can I conditionally add a title based on the state of the current element, i.e. when the current element's text-overflow: ellipses property is triggered?

```
<div className="shortDiv" 
     :title={isTruncated(CURRENT_ELEMENT) ? long_data : null}>
  {{long_data}}
</div>
```

I can't use `ref="shortDiv" ... isTruncated(this.shortDiv.current)` because `this[ref]` in *isTruncated* comes back *undefined*. I have inspected `this`, and it is properly the react component, but refs is an empty object.

So, the method I'm using is like this:

```
  isTruncated (ref) {
    let el = this[ref].current

    return (el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth)
  }
```

an an example of an element it is attached to is:

```
<figcaption ref="figcaption-name" 
            title={this.isTruncated('figcaption-name')? name: null}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        elementContent: <div>CONTENT HERE</div>,
        title: "TITLE",
    }
```

or perhaps a state like this to manage your entire element

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        element_to_truncate:{
            content:  <div>CONTENT HERE</div>,
            title: "TITLE",
            is_truncated: false,
            other_variables: ...
        }
    }
```

So then when you change the state of the element, itll change the content on the fly.

```
<div className="shortDiv" 
     :title={this.state.elementTitle}>
</div>
```

and then wherever you want to process the isTruncated() vs long_data, set the state to the value so it'll always change. So, maybe:

```
if(isTruncated()){ return truncated }else{ return long_data }
```

No need to use a ref or currentElement business.

Comment: but I need to set `elementTitle` to either the same as `elementContent` (the text in the element),or null, depending on whether the element _currently_ has text-overflow ellipsis set. I definintely need the current Element to do that .. I'll add the isTruncated method so you get a bteter sense of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that you understand. `isTruncated` must check to see _if the rendered div with_ `text-overflow: ellipsis` _in fact has ellipsis or not._ This is determined by the browser's implementation of the box model as applied to the element in its rendered context. In the case that it does, the full length of its contents will be added to the title, so you can actually see the non-rendered text.